# Reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 system doesn't show my sound card (I hear No Sound at all)

Tags: sound

Reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04,  system doesn't show my sound card. Now
I have No Sound at all (speakers or headphones)

Never before I had problems with the sound.
I was watching (and hearing) a youtube movie in the same pc where ubuntu was reinstalling.

I verified the audio is not muted.

The screenshot shows a card called **Salida para torpes** (output for fatheads) I don't know what that means or how to fix the sound problem.

[image]

This is another screenshot from the live cd (Try Ubuntu option) where I can hear sound both in the speaker and the headphones:
[image]

**ADDED AFTER SOLUTION:**

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Pegatron NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [1b0a:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:04.1 Multimedia controller [0480]: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Audio Capture [109e:0878] (rev 11)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Pegatron RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1b0a:0003]
```

Comment: "salida para torpes" is "dummy output" ie a fake sound card.

Comment: [ravery](https://askubuntu.com/users/694267/ravery):  So it's true: System is not recognizing my sound card. Let's Restart...

Comment: @ravery Do you have any idea why it's not showing his actual sound card (as per the question), or what he can do?

Comment: @L.D.James -- no I do not, there are many possibilities.... I was just clarifying what "salida para torpes" means because this is an English speaking site.... ie improving his question in terms of target audience

Comment: Thanks!  Now is clear which part of his question you were answering.  I has missed the part where he asked for a clarification of the card.

Comment: Run additional drivers from **Software & Updates**.  You can bring up the GUI application by typing `Software & Updated` in the Ubuntu Search button.  If the system detects the card, select it and run the `Apply Changes` option on the screen.  If it doesn't detect the card, giving you this option, please run `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` and append the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it making a fresh install of Ubuntu.

At the beginning I had chosen **Reinstall Ubuntu** to preserve my files 'cause I have only one partition. Now I decided to shrink the partition creating a new one of 30Gb where I made the fresh install.

Everything is alright now with the sound.
Thanks for comments.

Comment: Starting a fresh install can almost always get things working.  But for many lose the productivity of having to redo preferences and configuration.  In this case, you have a supported sound device.  The output of the command I gave you would have shown your sound card hardware.  Installing the proper drivers would have been a very simple matter.  You might have learned something valuable for your next glitch had you tested it and performed a followup.  By the way, the preserved files were your personal space `/home`.  Your previous **ReInstall** had removed everything else.

Comment: [L. D. James](https://askubuntu.com/users/29012/l-d-james): Thanks for your comments. I really appreciate them. I did follow your suggestions up to the point of "system detects the card" (it didn't) then I felt sort of "why I'm doing this?"  and begin the resizing and fresh install. Now I think I didn't read the **lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio** or I didn't understand it must be run in the terminal. Sorry. I've just tested it. Now I know for the next  glitch.